# English Windows 10 Home upgrade to Pro, using US activation key?

Tags: windows-10, upgrade, international

Is it possible to upgrade an English PC, running Windows 10 Home to Pro, using an activation key purchased in the U.S.?

Comment: The English PC is in England. The activation key for Pro is from the States.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to upgrade an English PC, running Windows 10 Home to
>   Pro, using an activation key purchased in the United States?

You can use your license key to install any version of Windows 10 Professional.  Windows 10 Professional keys are not tied to a specific region or language pack.